# How to vertically align inline-block divs without vertical spaces using CSS?

Tags: html, css, layout, vertical-alignment

I have special problem which I am trying to solve using CSS. My HTML layout is like this:

```
<div id="body">
    <div id="box1">lorem ipsum...</div>
    <div id="box2">lorem ipsum...</div>
    <div id="box3">lorem ipsum...</div>
    <div id="box4">lorem ipsum...</div>
</div>
```

and CSS is this:

```
div { display:inline-block;vertical-align:top }
#body { width:400px;outline:1px solid #eee }
#box1 { background-color:red;width:250px; }
#box2 { background-color:blue;width:150px }
#box3 { background-color:green;width:150px }
#box4 { background-color:yellow;width:150px }
```

The result then looks like this:

[image: what I've got now]

But my desired result should look like this picture below. It's hard for me to describe it in words so I've just uploaded this graphic mock-up so you would get the idea what I want to achieve. Basically, the empty space between first and second row of boxes should disappeared and text in box #4 should "float" around box #2. I want only CSS solution if it is possible and it doesn't need to support IE7 and below:

[image: what I want]

Here is jsFiddle for this scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/HUxWZ/

Anybody can help please ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is very hard and will require some crazy tricks. As far as I can see, you would have to split the blue div into two or three parts (one of which would have to be a child of the yellow one). Is that acceptable?

Comment: You might want to check out [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), if you're not averse to using jQuery.

Comment: You could change `#box1` and `#box2` to `#box1 { background-color:red;width:250px;position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px; }` and  `#box2 { background-color:blue;width:100px;position:fixed;top:0px;left:250px;}` and align them accordingly. Not sure about how efficient it is but it seems to work with Safari

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been fiddling a bit, this is my best shot:

http://jsfiddle.net/HUxWZ/10/

And with a touch of jQuery magic to make the text in yellow box flow around the blue one:

http://jsfiddle.net/HUxWZ/21/

Comment: Except the text in the yellow box doesn't flow around the shape of the blue box.

Comment: @ptriek - i've just tried your solution also in IE8 and it doesn't look good. I said that I don't need it to work in IE7 below, but I need it to work IE8. I tried myself to fix it, but with no luck. Can you please take a look at it so your fiddle works in IE8 as well ?

Comment: @ptriek I'm sorry, I had more IEs opened at the time and I have mistakenly thought I have IE8, but it was IE7. Sorry. You are right, it works fine in IE8.